# Website no longer loading in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, production

My website has been running fine for a long time now:

However this morning I noticed that sometimes when I tried to access said site I was getting a 500 error then when I refreshed it would serve up the homepage.

so I reverted my unicorn config from "preload_app :true" to see if that solved the issue

however since re-deploying the application, I am getting the following error in my log and the application is refusing to load:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant CategoriesController):
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `each'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `constantize'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:69:in `controller_reference'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:54:in `controller'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.5.2.17) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:8:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.5.2.17) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__683269349__call__722494165__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  airbrake (3.1.6) lib/airbrake/rack.rb:41:in `call'
  airbrake (3.1.6) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  unicorn (4.2.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:530:in `process_client'
  unicorn (4.2.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:604:in `worker_loop'
  newrelic_rpm (3.5.2.17) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/unicorn_instrumentation.rb:18:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.5.2.17) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/unicorn_instrumentation.rb:18:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
  unicorn (4.2.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:487:in `spawn_missing_workers'
  unicorn (4.2.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:498:in `maintain_worker_count'
  unicorn (4.2.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:272:in `join'
  unicorn (4.2.1) bin/unicorn:121:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
  /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

I get the same error (obviously with the controller name changing) when I try accessing any other page or even the admin section of the site, I've spent a good few hours looking at this now and I honestly can't see the problem.

I have tried running the application in production on my local machine and it works fine.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I know this is stupid, but did you try restarting the rails server

Comment: Yes mohammad, I've restarted the rails server a number of times, with no success, when you try accessing the site through the browser its not even giving an error, its simply saying "oops that link appears to be broken"

Comment: run on your server machine $ `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like I have managed to fix this,

basically as a last resort I completely killed Unicorn on my production server and then started it up again, and sure enough the website came back to life :D

This isn't the best solution but at least now I can look into it while people can still access the site!

Comment: What does your `unicorn.rb` (or whatever you call your unicorn config file) look like?  It's possible that the master and worker processes aren't being killed because of some config problem...